# Load a dynamic python URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to load a dynamic URL generated by Python Django using jQuery.

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#loadDiv').load('localhost/home/{{ movie.id }}/add_question/');
});
```

How can I catch and load the link if it constantly changes?

Comment: whenever you have clicked the link then only its loaded isn't it? if the url constantly changes it'll be changed in the 'a' tag. The thing is whatever the time you click, it will take the value of href at that clicking time

Comment: from where "load a dynamic URL" a  file or db or anything else. will you give details little bit more.

Comment: What I mean is I want to capture all of the following URLs:localhost/home/1/add_question/                   localhost/home/2/add_question/                                    localhost/home/3/add_question/ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your template in a sensible manner, each link found therein will have a different link matching the item for that element. Assuming a named url called `movie_add`, taking a single parameter being the movie ID, make your template like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for movie in movies %}
  <li>{{ movie.name }} <a href="{% url movie_add movie.id %}">add</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<div id="loadDiv"></div>
```

Now each `a` tag will have a url that lets you add a question for that specific movie. From there on, the following script should do what you want:

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(data) {
      $('#loadDiv').html(data);
    }
  });
```